# Negate condition with awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I cant seem to figure out how to negate my condition with awk.

For example, lets say I have

```
g ha
a bb
g hc
f cd
t de
g pf
```

I can print just the ones with g and starts with h for the first and second column with:

```
cat test.txt | awk '$1 ~ /g/ && $2 ~ /^h/'
```

but how do I do the opposite, where I just want to print the ones that are not `g` and start with `h`.  Basically to have the output:

```
a bb
f cd
t de
g pf
```

Comment: Do the columns always contain only one character?

Comment: Actually good question, let me update

Comment: Have you tried `awk '! ($1 ~ /g/ && $2 ~ /^h/)'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$1 ~ /g/ && $2 ~ /h/` is true then continue with the next line otherwise output the current line.

```
awk '$1 ~ /g/ && $2 ~ /h/{next} {print}' test.txt
```

Output:

```
a b
f c
t d
g p
```

Comment: Cool yes this is what i am looking for.  Sorry I updated the question, but the answer holds

Answer (score 0):

You could also negate the whole match using `!`

As the first field is always a single character you can check if it is `g` without using a regex notation because `$1 ~ /g/` will still match if there is a `g` somewhere in the string.

```
awk '!($1 == "g" && $2 ~ /^h/)' test.txt
```

Output

```
a bb
f cd
t de
g pf
```

Answer (score 0):

The negation (opposite) of `$1 ~ /g/ && $2 ~ /^h/` or any other condition is simply sticking `!` at the front of it:

```
$ awk '!($1 ~ /g/ && $2 ~ /^h/)' file
a bb
f cd
t de
g pf
```

but you can also apply boolean algebra to that (`!(a && b)` = `!a || !b`) to get:

```
$ awk '$1 !~ /g/ || $2 !~ /^h/' file
a bb
f cd
t de
g pf
```